# Ampl Cplex QP Hessian is not positive semi-definite. No basis. error

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, quadratic, ampl

++The error that is appearing seems to be from non-linear constraints in my model file. I can not find the particular area of conflict. Attached below is the model file that I have on hand. I have tried removing the "=" from constraints as well as variable. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Hopefully the commentary will aid in understanding the setup, but the basic program is to find the optimal profit of production, shipment, and selling costs of sofas and chairs from different destinations.

```
 #Parameters

param I; #Number of Plants

param J; #Number of Products

param K; #Number of Raw Material

param P; #Number of Type of Paid hours

param L; #Number of Processes

param M; #Number of Supplies

param N; #Number of Cities

param r{k in 1..K,j in 1..J}; #amount of raw material k required per unit of product j

param q{j in 1..J}; #miscellaneous production cost (in dollars) per unit of product i produced

param z{p in 1..P}; #total type of working hours p (regular or overtime) available per month

param t{l in 1..L,j in 1..J,i in 1..I}; #time (in hours) required by process l to produce product j at plant i.

param e{p in 1..P}; #salary multiplier for regular/overtime (p) paid hours

param w{l in 1..L, i in 1..I}; #regular salary cost (in dollars) per hour for process l at plant i.

param c{m in 1..M,k in 1..K}; #cost (in dollars) per unit of raw material k from supplier m

param h{m in 1..M,i in 1..I}; #cost (in dollars) per unit of raw material shipped from supplier m to plant i.

param Price{j in 1..J,n in 1..N}; #selling price (in dollars) per unit of product j in city n.

param Low{j in 1..J,n in 1..N}; #minimum demand (in number of units) of product j in city n

param U{j in 1..I,n in 1..N}; #maximum demand (in number of units) of product j in city n

param s{j in 1..J,i in 1..I,n in 1..N}; #shipping cost (in dollars) for product j shipped from plant i to city n.

param D{m in 1..M,k in 1..K}; #maximum amount of raw material k available from supplier m per month.



#Decision Variables

var x{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,n in 1..N}>=0; #number of units of product j produced by regular hours, shipped from plant i to city n. and non-negativity

var y{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,n in 1..N}>=0; #number of units of product j produced by overtime hours, shipped from plant i to city n. and non-negativity

var d{m in 1..M,k in 1..K}>=0; # demand of raw material k required from supplier m. and non-negativity

var revenue=sum{i in 1..I, j in 1..J, n in 1..N}(x[i,j,n]*y[i,j,n])*Price[j,n]; #total revenue generated by selling products.

var rawMatCost=sum{m in 1..M,k in 1..K} d[m,k]*c[m,k]; #total cost of purchasing raw material.

var rawMatShipCost=sum{m in 1..M,k in 1..K,i in 1..I} d[m,k]*h[m,i]; #total cost of shipping raw material

var salCost=sum{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,l in 1..L,n in 1..N} (x[i,j,n]*e[1]+y[i,j,n]*e[2])*(t[l,j,i]*w[l,i]); #total salary paid.

var prodShipCost=sum{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,n in 1..N}(x[i,j,n]+y[i,j,n])*s[j,i,n]; #total cost of shipping products

var miscCost=sum{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,n in 1..N} (x[i,j,n]+y[i,j,n])*q[j]; #total miscellaneous cost.



#Objective function

maximize MonthProfit: 
(revenue-rawMatCost-rawMatShipCost-salCost-prodShipCost-miscCost); #Total Monthly Profit



subject to
RawConsumed1{k in 1..K}:sum{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,n in 1..N}(x[i,j,n]+y[i,j,n])*r[k,j]>=sum{m in 1..M}d[m,k]; #Raw Material Consumed

RawConsumed2{k in 1..K}:sum{i in 1..I,j in 1..J,n in 1..N}(x[i,j,n]+y[i,j,n])*r[k,j]<=sum{m in 1..M}d[m,k]; #Raw Material Consumed

rawSup{k in 1..K}:sum{m in 1..M}d[m,k]<=sum{m in 1..M}D[m,k]; #Raw Material Supplied

RegTConsum{i in 1..I,l in 1..L}:sum{j in 1..J,n in 1..N}x[i,j,n]*t[l,j,i]<=z[1]; #Regular Time consumption

OverTConsum{i in 1..I,l in 1..L}:sum{j in 1..J,n in 1..N}y[i,j,n]*t[l,j,i]<=z[2]; #Overtime Consumption

MinDemand{j in 1..J,n in 1..N}:sum{i in 1..I}(x[i,j,n]+y[i,j,n])>=Low[j,n]; #minimum Demand

MaxDemand{j in 1..J,n in 1..N}:sum{i in 1..I}(x[i,j,n]+y[i,j,n])<=U[j,n]; #Maximum Demand
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying `x*y`?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen That was my mistake, it has been changed.

Comment: @TJYen You still have an x*y in the formula for revenue.